# Java S3 upload large file (~ 1.5Tb) erroring out with ResetException. File is read/processed via InputStream

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, java-11

I have application running in Java. I have a large file that i encrypt and upload to S3. As file is huge, I cannot keep it in-memory and hence use PipedInput and PipedOutputStreams to do my encryption.
I have BufferedInputStream wrapping PipedInputStream which then passed to S3 PutObjectRequest. I have already calculated the size of encrypted object and added that to Objectmetadata.
Here are some code pieces:

```
PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream(uploadFileInfo.getPout(), MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(pis, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
LOG.info("Is mark supported? " + bis.markSupported());
PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(uploadFileInfo.getS3TargetBucket(),
                        uploadFileInfo.getS3TargetObjectKey() + ".encrypted",
                        bis, metadata);
//Set read limit to more than stream size expected i.e 20mb
// https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/427
LOG.info("set read limit to " + (MAX_BUFFER_SIZE + 1));

putObjectRequest.getRequestClientOptions().setReadLimit(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE + 1);
Upload upload = transferManager.upload(putObjectRequest);
```

My stack trace shows that `reset()` call to BufferedInputStream is throwing exception

```
[UPLOADER_TRACKER] ERROR com.xxx.yyy.zzz.handler.TrackProgressHandler - Exception from S3 transfer 
com.amazonaws.ResetException: The request to the service failed with a retryable reason, but resetting the request input stream has failed. See exception.getExtraInfo or debug-level logging for the original failure that caused this retry.;  If the request involves an input stream, the maximum stream buffer size can be configured via request.getRequestClientOptions().setReadLimit(int)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.resetRequestInputStream(AmazonHttpClient.java:1423)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1240)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5052)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4998)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doUploadPart(AmazonS3Client.java:3734)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadPart(AmazonS3Client.java:3719)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.uploadPartsInSeries(UploadCallable.java:258)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInParts(UploadCallable.java:189)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.call(UploadCallable.java:121)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:143)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Resetting to invalid mark
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(BufferedInputStream.java:448)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.reset(SdkFilterInputStream.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.reset(SdkFilterInputStream.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.InputSubstream.reset(InputSubstream.java:110)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.reset(SdkFilterInputStream.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.reset(SdkFilterInputStream.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.InputSubstream.reset(InputSubstream.java:110)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.reset(SdkFilterInputStream.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.MD5DigestCalculatingInputStream.reset(MD5DigestCalculatingInputStream.java:105)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.reset(SdkFilterInputStream.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.reset(ProgressInputStream.java:168)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.reset(SdkFilterInputStream.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.resetRequestInputStream(AmazonHttpClient.java:1421)
    ... 22 more
[UPLOADER_TRACKER] ERROR com.xxx.yyy.zzz.handler.TrackProgressHandler - Reset exception caught ==> If the request involves an input stream, the maximum stream buffer size can be configured via request.getRequestClientOptions().setReadLimit(int)
com.amazonaws.ResetException: The request to the service failed with a retryable reason, but resetting the request input stream has failed. See exception.getExtraInfo or debug-level logging for the original failure that caused this retry.;  If the request involves an input stream, the maximum stream buffer size can be configured via request.getRequestClientOptions().setReadLimit(int)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.resetRequestInputStream(AmazonHttpClient.java:1423)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1240)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5052)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4998)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doUploadPart(AmazonS3Client.java:3734)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadPart(AmazonS3Client.java:3719)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.uploadPartsInSeries(UploadCallable.java:258)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInParts(UploadCallable.java:189)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.call(UploadCallable.java:121)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:143)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Resetting to invalid mark
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(BufferedInputStream.java:448)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.reset(SdkFilterInputStream.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.reset(SdkFilterInputStream.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.InputSubstream.reset(InputSubstream.java:110)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.reset(SdkFilterInputStream.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.reset(SdkFilterInputStream.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.InputSubstream.reset(InputSubstream.java:110)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.reset(SdkFilterInputStream.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.MD5DigestCalculatingInputStream.reset(MD5DigestCalculatingInputStream.java:105)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.reset(SdkFilterInputStream.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.reset(ProgressInputStream.java:168)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.reset(SdkFilterInputStream.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.resetRequestInputStream(AmazonHttpClient.java:1421)
```

However I am adding readLimit to MAX_BUFFER_SIZE + 1. This is a reliability tip from AWS.
Anyone faced this issue earlier? Side points: since m encrypting the file i need to use inputstream as compared to File or FileInputStream. I dont have permissions to write on disk locally as well.

Comment: Can you post the link where you got this tip? I would expect _minus_ 1, not plus 1.

Comment: What is the value of `MAX_BUFFER_SIZE`?  How do you know it's sufficient?

Comment: Have you specified the file site in `metadata`? Otherwise the documentation states that the whole file have to be kept in memory before writing it: `Content length for the data stream must be specified in the object metadata parameter; Amazon S3 requires it be passed in before the data is uploaded. Failure to specify a content length will cause the entire contents of the input stream to be buffered locally in memory so that the content length can be calculated, which can result in negative performance problems.`

Comment: @Parsifal https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/best-practices.html

Comment: @JimGarrison currently its 40mb. I know its not sufficient, but i may have multiple files to upload, so cannot keep whole file in memory either ways. Sorry if you meant another thing on sufficient, please do explain

Comment: Yes i have specified the object content length, based on encryption algorithm. Files upto 20 gb are getting uploaded consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misinterpreting the recommendation. Quoting from the [link you provided](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/best-practices.html), with emphasis added:

> For example, if **the maximum expected size of a stream** is 100,000 bytes, set the read limit to 100,001 (100,000 + 1) bytes. The mark and reset will always work for 100,000 bytes or less. Be aware that this might cause some streams to buffer that number of bytes into memory.

As I interpret this, it configures the client to be able to locally buffer content from the source stream, *when that stream does not support mark/reset on its own.* This is consistent with [the documentation for `RequestClientOptions.DEFAULT_STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/RequestClientOptions.html#DEFAULT_STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE):

> Used to enable mark-and-reset for non-mark-and-resettable non-file input stream

In other words, it's used to buffer *an entire source stream* within the client, not to specify how large a chunk to send from the source stream. And in your case, I think it's ignored, because (1) you're not buffering the entire stream, and (2) the stream that you pass *does* implement mark/reset on its own.

A multi-part upload, which is what `TransferManager` is doing in your example, breaks the input stream into chunks of at least 5 MB (the actual chunk size depends on the declared size of the stream; for a 1.5 TB file it's around 158 MiB). These are uploaded using the `UploadPart` API call, which attempts to send an entire chunk at a time. If a part fails from a retryable cause, then the client attempts to reset the stream *to the start of the chunk.*

You can probably make this work by setting the read limit on your `BufferedInputStream` to a size large enough to hold a single part. The calculation that the transfer manager uses is [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/internal/TransferManagerUtils.java#L119); it's the size of the file divided by 10,000 (the maximum number of parts in a multi-part upload). So, again, 158 MiB. I'd use 200 MiB just to be safe (and because I'm sure you have bigger files).

If it were me, however, I would probably use the low-level multi-part upload methods directly. The main benefit of `TransferManger`, in my opinion, is to be able to upload a *file,* where it can utilize multiple threads to perform concurrent part uploads. With a stream, you have to process each part sequentially.

Actually, if it was me I'd seriously reconsider uploading a single 1.5 TB file. Yes, you can do it. But I can't imagine that you're downloading the entire file every time that you want to read it. Instead, I expect that you're downloading a byte range. In which case, you'll probably find it just as easy to work with, say, 1500 files that are each 1 GiB in size.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue with the S3 SDK and `BufferedInputStream`

See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/427#issuecomment-273550783

The simplest solution (even if not ideal) is to download the file locally and pass the `File` object to the S3 SDK like so

```java
InputStream inputStream = ...;
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("upload-temp", "")
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, file);  // or any other copy utility
PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, key, tempFile);
Upload upload = transferManager.upload(putObjectRequest);
tempFile.deleteOnExit();
```